# Cofinal subset equivalent to unbounded subset?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

As stated in the title, given a poset $(S,\leq)$ I think it's trivial that an unbounded subset $A \subseteq S$ is cofinal, but does the opposite implication hold?

**Definition 1.** A subset $X$ of a poset $(S,\leq)$ is said to be **cofinal** if: $\forall s \in S \; \exists x \in X \; s \leq x$.

**Definition 2.** A subset $X$ of a poset $(S,\leq)$ is said to be **bounded**: $\exists s \in S \; \forall x \in X \; x \leq s$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither implication holds.

In $(\mathbb{N}_+, \mid)$ the subset $\{ 2^n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is unbounded, but not cofinal.

In $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}), \subseteq)$ the subset $\{ \mathbb{N} \}$ is cofinal, but bounded.

Comment: Are there stronger hypothesis where any of the implications hold (e.g. if the poset is well-ordered/a (limit) ordinal)?

Comment: @leluch_l8r4, in a linear order, an unbounded sequence is cofinal. In a linear order without maximal element, the two properties are equivalent.

Comment: @leluch_l8r4 The weakest assumption under which cofinality implies unboundedness is that $(S, \leqslant)$ does not have a greatest element. The weakest sensible assumption for the converse seems to be that $(S, \leqslant)$ is a linear order, as the previous comment points out.